# Mobile Web - Disable long-touch/taphold text selection

Tags: android, iphone, css, mobile, highlight

I've seen/heard all about disabling text selection with the variations of `user-select`, but none of those are working for the problem I'm having. On Android (and I presume on iPhone), if you tap-and-hold on text, it highlights it and brings up little flags to drag and select text. I need to disable those (see image):

[image: screenshot]

I've tried `-webkit-touch-callout` to no avail, and even tried things like `$('body').on('select',function(e){e.preventDefault();return;});` to no avail. And the cheap tricks like `::selection:rgba(0,0,0,0);` won't work either, as hiding these won't help - selection still happens and it disrupts the UI. Plus I'm guessing those flags would still be there.

Any thoughts would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. The Fiddle seemed to work when I just tested it on my phone, but I'm not 100% sure it would work for me in production - I still need to be able to trigger events (notably, `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend`) on the elements. Although, considering this is only acting on `selectstart`, we might be good.

I'll test it out tonight and get back to you :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Reference:**

[**jsFiddle Demo with Plugin**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebEqu/)

The above jsFiddle Demo I made uses a Plugin to allow you to ***prevent any block of text from being selected*** in **Android** or **iOS** devices (along with desktop browsers too).

It's easy to use and here is the sample markup once the jQuery plugin is installed.

**Sample HTML:**

```
<p class="notSelectable">This text is not selectable</p>

<p> This text is selectable</p>
```

**Sample jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.notSelectable').disableSelection();

});
```

**Plugin code:**

```
$.fn.extend({
    disableSelection: function() {
        this.each(function() {
            this.onselectstart = function() {
                return false;
            };
            this.unselectable = "on";
            $(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none');
            $(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none');
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Per your message comment:** *`I still need to be able to trigger events (notably, touchstart, touchmove, and touchend) on the elements.`*

I would simply would **use a wrapper** that is **not** affected by this plugin, yet it's text-contents are protected using this plugin.

To allow interaction with a link in a block of text, you can use `span tags` for all but the link and add class name `.notSelected` for those `span tags` only, thus preserving selection and interaction of the anchors link.

**Status Update:** This updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebEqu/1/) confirms you concern that perhaps other functions may not work when text-selection is disabled. Shown in this updated jsFiddle is jQuery Click Event listener that will fire a Browser Alert for when the Bold Text is clicked on, even if that Bold Text is not text-selectable.

Comment: This does NOT work for my Android 2.3.3,,, Just went to the your jsFiddle and tried it out. Selected all of the text. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. After the JsFiddle webpage has loaded, hit the RUN button before testing. Also, while you technically can select all the text, doing a copy of that and pasting into the next document will not paste the blocked portion of text. If still this is an issue, I will try to access a Android device with that version number. Thoughts?

Comment: +1 Fantastic, thanks @arttronics! What variation might prevent the context menu from showing on "long touch"?

Answer (score 71):

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

This will disable it for every browser going.

Comment: Not to be mean, but did you read the question at all?? I have exactly that plastered all over my CSS (from individual IDs/classes all the way up to the body and `*`), and I explicitly stated hiding the highlighting is a bad idea....

Comment: Yes, I did read your post. Now, did you actually try the code? It has -webkit-touch-callout added and the correct way to prevent the highlight overlay using -webkit-tap-highlight-color. I use this in my webapps and it works fine - no content menu, no highlighting and no selection.

Comment: I suppose I didn't mention originally, but I've had `-webkit-touch-callout:none;` in there the entire time as well. The only thing `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` would do would be make the highlight transparent, __not__ disable it. I didn't bother with the code initially because it wasn't anything I hadn't seen before, but just to appease you I tried it and it didn't work. What OSes/devices have you tested on that it worked? Not working on Android 2.3 or 3.0...

Comment: Thanks! Worked great for me. On Android 4.4.4 / Chrome

Comment: Best way to do it - pure CSS, no extra JS or plugins.

Answer (score 2):

-webkit-user-select:none; wasn't supported on Android until 4.1 (sorry).

Comment: So there's no way to get rid of/prevent it?! :(