# How to prevent selection of canvas on a long touch/ taphold using HTML5 / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using Kinetic.js library for handling my touch events and other canvas related objects for a HTML5 mobile game. The library provides easy interface to access all events however, it does not have a handle for catching long-touch/taphold event.
My game requires users to touch-hold the key to continue fire but this selects the entire canvas which requires an additional click to deselect which becomes annoying when done repeatedly.
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237936/mobile-web-disable-long-touch-taphold-text-selection) discussion but no solution is accepted there.

Comment: e.preventDefault() inside my own object(using the library) event handler din't help

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() is what you use to prevent the browser's default behavior and event.stopPropagation() is what you use to prevent competing event handlers from firing.
For IE: window.event.cancelBubble = true

Try using stopPropagation()

to get the event you can do:

```
 function(e) {
   var event = e || window.event;
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   // more code
 }
```