# android phonegap touch shadow

Tags: android, cordova, touch

Android/Phonegap, I create a pop window at index.html, when I touch move the content of pop window, the shadow of button will display. as picture display blow:

[image]

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237936/mobile-web-disable-long-touch-taphold-text-selection

Comment: I have fixed it with css styles: 
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 0):

DMDGeeker is dam right! Thanks bro this code is working just fine! had to deal with this issue several minutes until i find your comment

```
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```