# Disable selection on swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, swipe, onselect

I'm changing a script (found on www.dynamicdrive.com) for being used with Jquery 1.4, so I could use it within Drupal 7. My version of it is live at http://screamingsilence.be/js/touchGallery/

All is working well, but when I view it on my Android tablet/smartphone, the images gets selected and that doesn't look very pretty.

I tried this code, but this doesn't help:

```
$('img').attr('unselectable','on').bind('selectstart', function(){ return false; })
```

Comment: any update on this one?

Answer (score 1):

apply the following css style on the images **parent / container**:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Tried that already, this also didn't solve the problem. I'm not even sure the image or container gets selected. It seems more of a android issue. On tab it also turns "blue"... No idea why.

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237936/mobile-web-disable-long-touch-taphold-text-selection