# Mobile Site - Make elements not selectable

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hello I am trying to disable selecting items on my mobile site. I can do this fine on a normal site with the following css class

```
.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

but it does not work on the mobile. I am using AngularJS Is there something to disable the user from selecting items via touch?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237936/mobile-web-disable-long-touch-taphold-text-selection

Answer (score 0):

The most standard way to do this is with the disabled="disabled" attribute value pair in the HTML element you want to disable.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Is there a reason you're not using this?  Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like this:

```
    document.getElementById("Id").disabled = true;
```

I don't particularly understand why you are recreating something that has essentially been implemented already.