# How to disable text selection on touch press?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage which should run as a native app in windows so i have to disabled all browser stuff like text selection etc.

I managed to disable the text selection in a normal device like this:

```
$("body, html").mousedown(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But when i run that website in a touch screen device and i long press the text it still select it.

How can i disable the text selection even on touch devices?

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237968/4510870 might help you.

Comment: Find your selector that has the text and put `pointer-events:none;`      `$('#yourText').css('pointer-events','none');`

Comment: @OrisSin i actually have lot of text elements and i would be able to do it once for all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this in your CSS..

```
 -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome */     
           -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none;
```

Comment: This appears to work when added to the css of the body element for iOS Safari 13.7, otherwise it jumps to the nearest selectable element.

Comment: Works fine for table rows with MUI in react, thanks!